# bash script to collect pids in array

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, awk

Working on a simple bash script that I can use to ultimately tell me if a rogue process is running that we don't want - this one will ultimately be running with a different parent pid.  a monitor of sorts.  Where I'm having an issue is getting all the specific pids that I want into an array that I can perform some actions on.  Script first:

```
#!/bin/bash
rmanRUNNING=`ps -ef|grep /etc/process/process.conf|egrep -v grep|wc -l`

if [ $rmanRUNNING -gt 0 ]
 then
    rmanPPID=( $(ps -ef|grep processname|egrep -v grep|egrep -v /etc/process/process.conf|awk '{ printf $3 }') )
    for i in "${rmanPPID[@]}"
    do
        :
        echo $i
    done
fi
```

So, goal is to check for existence of the main process, this is the one running with the config file in it, the first variable tells me this.  Next, if it's running (based on the count greather than 0) the intention is to populate an array with all the parent pids, excluding what would be determined as the main process (we don't need to analyze this one).  So, in the array definition we get the list of processes, grep process name, egrep -v the grep output, also egrep -v the "main" process and then awk the parent pids then iterate through and attempt to echo each one individually (more would be done in this section, but it's not working).  Unfortunately, when I output $i all of the parent pids are simply concatenated together in one long string.  If I try to output a specific array item I get an empty output.

Obviously the question here is, what's wrong with my array definition that is preventing it from being declared as an array, or some other odd thing.

This is on RHEL, 6.2 on the test environment, probably 7 in production by the time this is live.

Full disclosure, I'm a monitoring engineer, not an SA - definitely not a bash scripter by nature!

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: just for clarity, an echo to screen of the PIDs is NOT the end desired output, it's just a simple way to test that I'm getting back what I'm expecting.  Based on comment below I believe pgrep type output is the preferred output.  In the end I'll be tying these pids back one at a time against the original process to ensure that it is the parent, and if it is not I'll spit out an error.

Comment: How about simple `PPIDs=($( ps -oppid= $(pgrep -f 'processname.*/etc/process/process.conf')))`

Comment: Why didn't you know to use `$(...)` at line 2 but you did know to use it at line 6?

Comment: @EdMorton At line 2 I'm not trying to write values into an array, simply getting a count of running processes matching my criteria.

Comment: I know but that has nothing to do with executing a command. Use of backticks to do so is obsolete, you should be using `$(...)` syntax everywhere.

Comment: Note that rather than running the `ps` pipeline twice (or minor variants on it), you should simply assign the PPID values to the array, and then check how many elements are in the array.

Comment: As an aside, `result=$(something | grep something | wc -l); if [ $result -gt 0 ]` is a really poor paraphrase of `if something | grep -q something` (unless of course you really do need the exact number of matches down the line, in which case `grep -c` does that).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not so much `$i` that will be one concatenated number, as well as that your array is just a single element of that concatenated number. This is because the output of `awk` is concatenated together, without any separator.

If you simply add a space within `awk`, you may get what you want:

```
rmanPPID=( $(ps -ef|grep processname | ... | awk '{ printf "%d ", $3 }') )
```

or even simpler, use `print` instead of `printf`:

```
rmanPPID=( $(ps -ef|grep processname | ... | awk '{ print $3 }') )
```

(Thanks to Jonathan Leffler, see comment below.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler good point: I overlooked `printf` vs `print`.